# html / php form that on submit does not process but only goes to a blank screen with the php file name.

Tags: php, html

Here is the php of the contact.php file the html calls.
Would appreciate any help with this im losing it trying to find the missing piece.
I tried ot use the error checking but no luck. When we submit it just stops at contact.php there is no code on the back and it does not send an email at all. It was sending before just not all the lines and I can not find the missing or mistaken character.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

$field_business = $_POST['cf_business'];
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_number = $_POST['cf_number'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'matt@igtechsolutions.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name.;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_business."\n";
$body_message .= 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone Number: '.$field_number."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@igtechsolutions.com');
    window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `subject` line looks decidedly dodgy. You probably need an extra `\r\n` there.

Comment: `.$field_name.;` => note the `.` before the `;`. An editor with syntax highlighting helps, what helps even more is setting those error reporting & display_errors settings in .htacess, php.ini, or server config, as it will never show you parse errors in the way you use them now.

Comment: Have you tried sending an e-mail using static data, like `mail("you@example.com","Subject goes here","Body is here");` I had an issue with `sendmail` that caused similar results. As @MikeW said, you should only use `\r\n` in e-mail commands to conform with [RFC2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt). And @Wrikken is correct.